# How can I connect my 240v well pump when all I have is a 120v control box?

Tags: well-pump

I have this well pump, item title is "[VEVOR Submersible Pump 3HP Deep Well Pump 32.8' Cable 4" 220V 630' w/Control Box](https://www.ebay.com/itm/373845132981)".

[image]

The pump needs 220 volts to run but the control box has a plug for a 110 outlet
My question is how does this work with a 110 plug control box ?

Comment: I have attempted to make the title question a more succinct version of the question (as is expected here). Please ensure that I've got this correct. Also, please [edit] to clarify what `32.8' Cable 4" 220V 630'` means.  Usually the `'` mark indicates feet, however, I'm not sure I understand how that impacts the numbers you've provided. Also, what does `Cable 4"` mean? The `"` usually denotes inches - is something in a 4" conduit? Is the cable 4" around? Does the `"` note denote inches in this case? The more you can clarify the more likely we are to be able to help you.

Comment: If the cable is two hots, one neutral and a ground wire, then it is easy to have an 120v outlet, not usually recommended nor usually in code, but possible.

Comment: I _think_ it's "32.8 foot cable" and a "4 inch [pump]" (the actual pump is 4 inches across).   (Don't know what "630 feet" means)

Comment: And lo, the string of gibberish turns up a website selling a 220V 50 Hz pump, so unless (or even if, for that matter) Jay is in a 50 Hz country... Return it and get something not from a terrible website selling unlisted junk that won't work on the power you have, and with incorrect connectors to boot? 630 ft head, but supplied with 32 feet of cable - yeah, that's not going to work. Junk - run. get your money back if you can, write it off as the cost of being gullible while shopping on the internet if you can't.

Comment: [This is probably the pump the OP has](https://www.vevor.com/deep-well-pump-c_11104/submersible-well-pump-630ft-42gpm-230v-3hp-deep-stainless-steel-water-pump-p_010727175534?gclid=CjwKCAjwj42UBhAAEiwACIhADsvp7qadY0IqNAShoVrEu56-QZphnFu2_R_PZDvm7-hbnObf4jfX9RoCSIoQAvD_BwE). From personal experience with this company, their online product listings are not always entirely accurate (I purchased an air compressor from them which actually turned out to have a better spec than advertised), so it's *possible* that what the OP received is actually a 60Hz pump ...

Comment: @FreeMan figured it out.  When you see a string of capitalized words like that, I find it often a cut-and-paste of the item *title* from the sales website. (perhaps it's an attempt to link the product?)  So I went looking, and found exactly that in the usual places.  Linked.

Comment: And for anyone who hasn't figured it out, 32.8' is a too-precise translation of 10 meters.

Comment: Valid point, @Harper-ReinstateUkraine, and I have often done the same. It's a shame, though, that when people go asking for free help from random strangers, that they can't be bothered to try to provide as much, clear info as possible up front instead of making the free helpers go figure out what they meant before actually getting to the work (for free) of figuring out the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First stop is the UL Listing.

Make sure the machine has a UL, CSA or ETL listing, or other Recognized Testing Lab required by your country.

Why? There's a lot of cheap junk out there sold mail order which is not safe, not well made, and not legal for sale or installation in this country. **That stuff will not provide satisfaction** in the long term, and is best avoided.

I mention this because sticking a 120V plug on a 240V appliance is the kind of "don't care" mistake we see *a lot of* on cheap junk mail order products.  Buyer beware!

Presuming it is listed by an appropriate lab, the instruction will also have been approved.  It is important to follow them, as they are the basis of the testing, approval and warranty.   Perhaps the control box is powered separately from the pump.